# Show icon on product on each page

Tags: magento, module, block

I'm using custom block to show my module logo over each product, now since `catalog_product_view` tag it shows the logo at product details page only, the problem is that I want to show the icon on each page on each product, whether it is home page, product list, detail, etc. how to achieve this using blocks

Here is the code

Module Configuration (app\etc\modules\NS_Mymodule.xml)

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <NS_Mymodule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </NS_Mymodule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Configuration XML (app\code\community\NS\Mymodule\etc\config.xml)

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <NS_Mymodule>
            <version>1.0.1</version> 
        </NS_Mymodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <Mymodule>
                <class>NS_Mymodule_Helper</class>
            </Mymodule>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <mymodule>
                <class>NS_Mymodule_Block</class>
            </mymodule>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mymodule>
                    <file>mymodule.xml</file>
                </mymodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Block Class ( app\code\community\NS\Mymodule\Block\Showicon.php )

```
class Ns_Mymodule_Block_Showicon extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function myfunction()
    {
        return "Hello tuts+ world";
    }
}
```

Layout XML ( app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\mymodule.xml)

```
<layout version="1.0.1">
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="mymodule/showicon" as="ns_media" name="mymodule_showicon" template="mymodule/showicon.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Template File (app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\mymodule\showicon.phtml)

```
<h1>SHOW ICON HERE</h1>
```

and in the app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('ns_media') ?>
```

right after

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
```

Comment: you want to list icon on each page .. or you want to list icon with products on home page, list page and product page

Comment: @PankajPareek actually at product image where ever they occur, so either it is home page, list or detail where ever we are showing product the icon must show over the image

Comment: If you check on the list page image is coming directly using code not from child block. so you have to override these templates in your extension

Comment: can you please help with any sample code or direction something?

Comment: you can check here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21460/override-template-file